# extract jsonb value from json containing json array in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, select, jsonb

I have json column which as data like this-

```
{"image_pose_array": [{"image_name": "0026568143_WS.jpg", "image_pose": "EXTRA", "is_blurred": false, "is_dark": false}], "policy_number": "\"D000000000\""}
```

how can i generate a report which would look like below -

```
image_name        | image_pose    |
-----------------------------------
0026568143_WS.jpg |  EXTRA        |
```

I tried as

```
SELECT  response #>>'{image_pose_array,0}' as json
FROM abcd_abcd.table_data
where policy_number ='D017447997' 
order by request_id  asc;
```

how to extract key's values from it?

Comment: What if the array contains more than one object, how would the result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#>` to access the whole object from the array and then access each key:

```
SELECT response #> '{image_pose_array,0}' ->> 'image_name' as image_name, 
       response #> '{image_pose_array,0}' ->> 'image_pose' as image_pose
from abcd_abcd.table_data
where policy_number ='D017447997' 
order by request_id  asc;
```

The difference between `#>` and `#>>` (what you used) is, that `#>` returns a `jsonb` value again which can then be accessed further. Whereas `#>>` returns a `text` value.

Alternatively you can use the `#>>` with one more step in the "path" argument:

```
response #>> '{image_pose_array,0,image_name}' as image_name,
response #>> '{image_pose_array,0,image_pose}' as image_pose
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `json[b]_array_elements()`. This accommodates the case when the array contains more than one object (in this situation, the query would generate one row per embedded object):

```
select 
    t.request_id,
    x.obj ->> 'image_name' as image_name,
    x.obj ->> 'image_pose' as image_pose
from digit_bots.t_fourwheeler_analysis_data t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'image_pose_array') as x(obj) 
where policy_number ='D017447997' 
order by request_id desc
```